# Running two batch files in one build step of TeamCity 9

Tags: batch-file, teamcity

I am using TeamCity 9. I want to run two batch files one after another in one build step.

If I write this in a build step:

```
BATCH_1.bat <arg1> <arg2> 
BATCH_2.bat <arg1> <arg2>
```

Only `BATCH_1.bat` gets executed... I changed sequence, then only `BATCH_2.bat` got executed. That means, only first batch file in build step is getting executed and control moves to next build step.

When I separated build steps, both batch files got executed. But when I bring them in one step, Only one executes.

Interesting thing is `ECHO` statements get executed before `BATCH_1` but not after it.

Is there any restriction that only one batch file can be executed in a build step?

Comment: Try using `CALL BATCH.....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way TeamCity works when using the command step is that it puts all the commands in your step into a single `.cmd` file and asks the command line interpreter to execute it.

So this is not a limit of TeamCity, it is a limit of the command line interpreter.

To have the interpreter return back to your first batch file (the one TeamCity generated) you will have to *call* the other batch files.

Try this:

```
CALL BATCH_1.bat <arg1> <arg2> 
CALL BATCH_2.bat <arg1> <arg2>
```